# Group or extract elements from Tupled list by their names c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am writing an litle c# app that extracts information from one source and prints it to a txt file. But I got a bit of a problem when coming to ordering the information. 
I have an tupled list like this:

```
List<Tuple<string,string,string>>
```

In this list i have elements that goes like this:

```
(SomeName1, SomeID1, Description1)
(SomeName2, SomeID2, Description1)
(SomeName3, SomeID3, Description1)
(SomeName4, SomeID4, Description1)
(SomeName5, SomeID5, Description1)
(SomeName6, SomeID6, Description2)
(SomeName7, SomeID7, Description2)
(SomeName8, SomeID8, Description2)
(SomeName9, SomeID9, Description2)
```

etc. 
So as we can see the name and ID is always unique. While the description is the same for several elements. What I want is to group up the list, or extract the elements from the list into several other lists based on their description. So I for example get two listst from the above list. Where list 1 will contain the following:

```
(SomeName1, SomeID1, Description1)
(SomeName2, SomeID2, Description1)
(SomeName3, SomeID3, Description1)
(SomeName4, SomeID4, Description1)
(SomeName5, SomeID5, Description1)
```

while list two will contain this:

```
(SomeName6, SomeID6, Description2)
(SomeName7, SomeID7, Description2)
(SomeName8, SomeID8, Description2)
(SomeName9, SomeID9, Description2)
```

Any sudgestions of how I can get this? Assumed I do not know what the description is, nor how many different descriptions they are. The optimal solution would be if I could get list1 to first show the description at index 0, followed by name, id and description at the following index. But I can manage to find that my self I think. The thing I cant get to work is to group/split the big list based on the description 
I would appritiate all the help I can get. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = input.GroupBy(t=>t.Item3, (key,items)=>items.ToList()).ToList();
// 
//list1 = result[0];
//list2 = result[1]; ...
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was searching for! :)